# Force Python import to be absolute (ignore local package directory)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

Is there a way to force an import to be absolute instead of relative?

I am "overriding" the Python standard library `json` module, so in my projects I always use the correct encoder and parameters:

`project/foo/json.py`: (mark this filename)

```
import json as pyjson

class ComplexEncoder(pyjson.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if hasattr(obj, 'isoformat'):
            return obj.isoformat()
        else:
            if type(obj) == file:
                return "filestream"
            raise TypeError, 'Object of type %s with value of %s is not JSON serializable' % (type(obj), repr(obj))

def dumps(data):
    return pyjson.dumps(data, cls=ComplexEncoder, check_circular=False, separators=(',', ':'), ensure_ascii=False)

def loads(data):
    return pyjson.loads(data)
```

When I import this file I get the dreaded `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'JSONEncoder'`. 
A `print(pyjson.__file__)` confirms my suspicion that `import json as pyjson` imports `json` from the local package instead of from the Python standard library.

Is there a way to force the import to be absolute, so the local directory is ignored?

Comment: Why not just name it with another name?

Comment: Because: A - means refactoring a lot of stuff. B - I had this problem a couple of times before and now I want a good generic solution.

Comment: Is `foo/json.py` intended for use in your code only, or might it be used by external code that just assumes it is getting the "real" `json` module? That latter does not sound particularly safe, and the former can be solved by simply doing `import myjson as json` instead of trying to "subclass" the module.

Comment: @chepner: I must hold back not to insert some Matrix quotes here regarding "real" ;) And since we are still using the default json module I don't see the unsafe here. But, you are right, I should just have given it a distinct name. However refactoring the codebase that depends on this is just to error prone...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your "json" module is inside a package, then this will fix it:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

With that `__future__` statement, imports will be absolute be default - i.e. it will only look for a top-level module or file called `json`.

If you need to import your local one, you can either do `import foo.json`, or you can explictly ask for a relative import using `from . import json` or `from .json import dumps`.

(I am assuming you're using Python 2).

Comment: `from __future__ import absolute_import` didn't work for me

Comment: This question is about Python 2, and that statement only works in Python 2.  If you're using Python 2 in 2022, you need to update to Python 3.  If you are using Python 3, this question is not relevant, ask your own question.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the self path from the sys.path:

```
self_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
if self_dir in sys.path:
    sys.path.remove(self_dir)
```

Then import the json as regular.

If you need to import anything from the local directory, just append the path to the sys.path and import what you need:

```
sys.path.append(self_dir)
from local_module import *
```